# Django: File Does Not Exist on edit of record. I don't want to update that field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form that requires an xls file to be uploaded on first submittal. When I go into edit a record, I don't want to have to re-upload another XLS necessarily. In fact, the xls may not be available. I can't wrap my head around how I would override the save method or forms to say effectively 'hey this time keep the same xls you have and ignore whatever is in that field.' I want to effectively keep the file link to download the initial xls there on the form so that the initial xls can be edited, yet set that to be an empty field and not required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two forms - one for adding, another for editing.

```
class MyAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'xls_file']

class MyEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'xls_file']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['xls_file'].required = False
```

Comment: My confusion is how do you set these forms to be used. I see that in the admin.py file you would set form= something, but how does it know the difference between the add form and the edit form? Does Django pick this up from the naming convention? If so then what do you set form= to? Thanks for the help, I am studying examples AND the documentation and this discrepancy is unclear. They all just say how to override a form, not the difference between add and edit.